# Two different recipes names providing same package with different versions. How can one force a default one?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, googletest

I have my Yocto environment (on meta-oe/recipes-test) the old `gmock` and `gtest` libs.

Nowadays I want to update it to newest release, although both libs were merged into a new one called `googletest`. To achieve that I'm adding the new recipe for `googletest` [(here's the recipe)](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/108109/) into a new layer already created by me. **Keep in mind this new version `PROVIDES += gmock gtest`**

So far so good. Here's the tricky part, on my image `layer.conf` I added this:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_gtest ?= "googletest"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_gmock ?= "googletest"
PREFERRED_VERSION_gtest ?= "1.8.1"
PREFERRED_VERSION_gmock ?= "1.8.1"
```

So I keep getting several errors, I'll try to split them here:

**FIRST:**

```
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gtest not available (for item gtest)
NOTE: versions of gtest available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gmock not available (for item gmock)
NOTE: versions of gmock available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gtest not available (for item gtest-staticdev)
NOTE: versions of gtest available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gtest not available (for item gtest-dev)
NOTE: versions of gtest available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gmock not available (for item gmock-dev)
NOTE: versions of gmock available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gmock not available (for item gmock-staticdev)
NOTE: versions of gmock available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gtest not available (for item gtest)
NOTE: versions of gtest available: 1.7.0
NOTE: preferred version 1.8.1 of gmock not available (for item gmock)
NOTE: versions of gmock available: 1.7.0
```

**SECOND:**

```
Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide gmock (PATH/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-test/gmock/gmock_1.7.0.bb PATH/sources/my-meta/recipes-test/googletest/googletest_1.8.1.bb).
     This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.
    ERROR: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide nativesdk-gmock (virtual:nativesdk:PATH/sources/my-meta/recipes-test/googletest/googletest_1.8.1.bb virtual:nativesdk:PATH/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-test/gmock/gmock_1.7.0.bb).
     This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.
    ERROR: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide gtest (PATH/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-test/gtest/gtest_1.7.0.bb PATH/sources/my-meta/recipes-test/googletest/googletest_1.8.1.bb).
     This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.
    ERROR: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide nativesdk-gtest (virtual:nativesdk:PATH/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-test/gtest/gtest_1.7.0.bb virtual:nativesdk:PATH/sources/my-meta/recipes-test/googletest/googletest_1.8.1.bb).
     This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.
```

As I said I still get several different errors, but generically speaking, the question is:

**TL;DR**

How can I make a recipe that doesn't have the exact same name of what it provides to be choosen by bitbake as default instead a previous version of it which HAS the recipe name identical of what it provides? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the first problem I believe you should use the recipe name after PREFERRED_VERSION, so `PREFERRED_VERSION_googletest ?= "1.8.1"`

Comment: Can you post the rest of your layer.conf? If yourlayer priority is higher than the layer which provides the older recipies it should select yours automatically. PREFERRED_VERSION should be placed into your distro.conf if your have one.

Comment: @FlorianBerndl In the end, I could fix it only having the `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_gmock ?= "googletest" and the same for `_gtest` and it ran as expected. I think it had a conflict by having PROVIDER and VERSION at the same place where only PROVIDER was needed.